# PHP Value from Array

Tags: php, arrays

I'm trying to work out how to get values from one of three arrays based on the array name.

```
$ABC001 = array('A'=>'10','B'=>'2','C'=>'1.0');
$ABC002 = array('A'=>'20','B'=>'4','C'=>'1.1');
$ABC003 = array('A'=>'30','B'=>'6','C'=>'1.2');
```

I have a variable passed to my script it will be contain something like `ABC@001` or `ABC@002`

I'm removing the @ so the var value now matches the array name/

```
$test = str_replace('@','',$var);
```

If I do `var_dump ( $$test )` I get all the values from the correct array, but if I do `echo $$test['A']`  or `echo $$test[0]`  I don't get the value from the first key in the correct array.

Can someone advise how to do this.

Thanks

Comment: Create one array: `$ABC = ['001' => ['A' => '10', ...], ...]`!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

try this ${$test} to get the values of the array

```
<?php

$ABC001 = array('A'=>'10','B'=>'2','C'=>'1.0');
$ABC002 = array('A'=>'20','B'=>'4','C'=>'1.1');
$ABC003 = array('A'=>'30','B'=>'6','C'=>'1.2');

$var = "ABC@002";

$test = str_replace('@','',$var);

var_dump(${$test}['A']);
```

Answer (score 3):

In order to use variable variables with arrays, you have to resolve an ambiguity problem. That is, if you write `$$test['A']` then the parser needs to know if you meant to use `$test['A']` as a variable, The syntax for resolving this ambiguity is:  `${$test}['A']` . Please check the documention here [PHP Variable Variable](http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.variable.php)